# Should I use a theme framework or start a Wordpress theme from scratch?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have worked with Wordpress for a couple of months and I have create a new theme for each project always, it is a manual process (creating templates files, function.php, style.css, import bootstrap.css, jquery, etc...). I don't know what is the best approach for it because it is a new design for  each project and I can't find a exact theme as the given for the designer (even a paid theme).

Now, I have a new project and I don't know if is better to use a Theme framework(such as Genesis, Elementor) to save time and for security/don't reinvent the wheel reasons or create a theme from scratch as always I've done. I'm worried about the limitations of use a tool like that instead of create everything from scratch.

These are the wireframes of my last project:

[image]

What are your suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I like to use https://understrap.com/ for all my projects.  It's based on Bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

I've worked from scratch for a long time untill I started using the same functions over and over, thats when I started my own little framework.

The downside for existing frameworks is the load of tools included you'll probably never use. You can always look into the code from Genesis eg and learn from other frameworks and projects, but keep abstracting functions/files from new projects into your own framework so it gets robust and really, it gets just like **you** want.

Answer (score 0):

1. Started with plain themes - waite of time every time.
2. Then picked up  html5 blank (http://html5blank.com/), did things faster but still needed nice frontend framework
3. Foundation Joints (http://jointswp.com/), lot of handy functions
4. Modified Joints to remove things which I don't need and added what was missing, happy with custom starter theme based on foundation 6